# Best solution for stopping a piece of code to be called multiple times?

Tags: c#

I have a method which is been called every 1 hour. But sometimes the method operations are not been completed fully within one hour and the method is again been called which causes confusion. So I have to find out if the previous method is been completed. Which is the best solution for this problem?

```
// will be called for every one hour  where the value will be repeated
// At sometimes it is possible for the same value to be called continually 
   for the next hour and at that time problem occurs
Void Method(int value)
{   
If(value =0)
    // Do some operations which may exceed one hour
Else If(value =1)
    // Do some operation’s which may exceed one hour
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How is this method called? Your post does not include any useful code to answer your question. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Method is been called by a thread which runs every one hour.

Answer (score 1):

One question would be what do you want to happen if the method is called while it is still running?

This code will just drop the 2nd call

```
private bool _running = false;
private readonly object _lock = new object();

void Method(int value)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        if (_running)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _running = true;
        }
    }

    if (value == 0)
    {
        // Do some operations which may exceed one hour
    }
    else if (value == 1)
    {
        // Do some operation’s which may exceed one hour
    }

    _running = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to save the state in a class field, so that the method checks to see if it's free to do some work or not. This will mean that if you call the method and it's busy, the work won't happen for your call:

```
private static bool methodIsBusy = false;

private static void WaitAndWriteMessage(TimeSpan waitTime, string message)
{
    // If we're busy, return right away
    if (methodIsBusy) return;

    // Let future calls know we're busy
    methodIsBusy = true;

    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
    Console.Write($"Method ran at: {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}. ");
    Console.WriteLine(message);

    // Allow future calls to run now
    methodIsBusy = false;
}
```

Our test method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => WaitAndWriteMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
            $"Method called at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}."));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

(Only the first of the three messages was printed)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Another idea is to use a `lock`, which means that calls to the method will pile up if the method is busy. All calls will eventually get completed, but if every call is longer than the iteration time in which the method is called, it will get further and further behind:

```
private static object methodLocker = new object();

private static void WaitAndWriteMessage(TimeSpan waitTime, string message)
{
    // Lock on a common object, so this call will wait
    // until there are no locks before it can continue
    lock (methodLocker)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
        Console.Write($"Method ran at: {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}. ");
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Our test method again:

```
private static void Main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Task.Run(() => WaitAndWriteMessage(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
            $"Method called at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}."));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

(Notice the difference between when the message was called and when it executed gets longer each time)

[image: ![enter image description here]